# Align a search icon and text inside a card

Tags: android, material-design

I'm trying to get a view like this for an android application where the "Search button" looks like a card at the top of the layout just below the toolbar (The "what are you looking for?" view in the Fiverr app picture below).

[image]

I want it to have the Search icon and some text next to it. I have tried this but it's jumbled up and doesn't just cut it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.home.HomeFragment"
    tools:ignore="ExtraText">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/searchCard"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:elevation="5dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_round_search_24"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/title_search"/>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap the icon and text inside a linear layout like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.home.HomeFragment"
    tools:ignore="ExtraText">
    
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/searchCard"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:elevation="5dp">
        
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_vertical">
    
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_round_search_24"/>
        
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/title_search"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you @just_user! This helped a lot. I don't know why I forgot about wrapping them in a `LinearLayout`.

Comment: @musale you could use a little less code if you add the icon as a compound drawable in text view instead of using its own view. In that case you might not need the linear layout, just set gravit center vertical in the text view and match_parent in both directions. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the search view for this purpose.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:ignore="ExtraText">

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/searchCard"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:elevation="5dp">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
        app:queryHint="Search"
        app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
        app:queryBackground="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Thank you @hasnain. This works however my use case entails clicking on that View and be redirected to a different view and not opening up the keyboard. That's why I chose to use a Card view. I appreciate this though it's less code.